# Fetch multiple files in the same ingestion spec in Apache Druid

Tags: druid

I want to fetch multiple files in the same ingestion spec. For example:

```
"ioConfig" : {
      "type" : "index_parallel",
      "firehose" : {
        "type" : "http",
        "uris" : [ "uri1", "uri2", "uri3" ],
        "maxFetchRetry" : 1,
      }
    }
```

But for this state, for example in the ***"uri1"***, druid tries to the fetch data. But if any error occurs, druid throws exception. In this state, Druid can not continue to fetch other files. How can I achieve that???

Flow of I want,

```
uri1 -- error
uri1 -- try again(do not try again after that due to max retry count)
uri2 -- success
uri3 -- success
```